# Is there a way to include db column name in java doc in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, javadoc

Our db tables have large number of columns and we would like to include the db columns in the java doc for the setters/getters in the JPA Entities. The column name is present as @Column JPA annotation.

Something like

```
/**
 * Mapped field for column 'ID_CLIENT'.
 */
@Column(name = "ID_CLIENT")
private Long clientId;
```

Comment: are you want to generate db table to entity class ?

Comment: No, I do not want to generate DB table. I want to auto generate java doc with information about table column name.